# Same string but different result

Tags: c

When i compile i have a different result (-6400 or -25 for s1 s2 (depends of gcc version) and -1 with array directly in memcmp), but the array are the same.

Thanks for help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("vrai %d\n", memcmp("qwertyuioa", "qwertyuioz", 10));
    char s1[] = "qwertyuioa";
    char s2[] = "qwertyuioz";
    printf("vrai s1 s2 %d\n", memcmp(s1, s2, 10));
}
```

Comment: So? That's perfectly within the specification.

Comment: But if you `memcmp("qwertyuioa", "qwertyuioa", 10);` you will always get `0`. [C11 Standard - 7.24.4 Comparison functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4)

Comment: But I have to agree that it is a little bit strange. How can `memcmp` see the difference?

Comment: It could be one call is optimized by the compiler to just `-1` and the second call isn't. Inspect the assembly.

Comment: It depends on `__STDC_ANALYZABLE__`.  Ondo, is that defined on your system?

Comment: Reinstate Monica, where can i see that ?

Comment: See [The mod firing squad: Stack Exchange embroiled in 'he said, she said, they said' row](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/)

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica I believe they were asking how to tell whether `__STDC_ANALYZABLE__` is available on their system, not about the token in your username.

Comment: Oh, that would be a bit different then `:)` In that case just add `#if defined (__STDC_ANALYZABLE__)` then next line `puts ("__STDC_ANALYZABLE__ is defined");` and next line `#endif` to your existing code, compile and run to check.

Answer (score 3):

From [memcmp(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp):

> The memcmp() function returns an integer **less than**, **equal to**, or **greater than** zero if the first n bytes of s1 is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than the first n bytes of s2.

The only thing that matters about the return value are is it less than zero, equalt to zero, or greater than zero.